# Проигрывание музыки из url потока чанками

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pyaudio

Всех приветствую. Есть сайт где транслируется радио - (https://listen4.myradio24.com/5129) не реклама!

Хочу python'ом читать оттуда поток секторами и воспроизводить его. Пробовал:

```
import requests
import pyaudio
import ffmpeg

url = 'https://listen4.myradio24.com/5129'  # replace with actual url

# get audio stream from url
res = requests.get(url, stream=True)
audio_stream = ffmpeg.input('pipe:0')

# play audio stream using pyaudio
with audio_stream.output('pipe:', format='rawaudio', layout='stereo') as out:
    with pyaudio.PyAudio() as audio:
        stream = audio.open(format=audio.get_format_from_width(out.get_sample_rate()),
                            channels=out.get_channels(),
                            rate=out.get_sample_rate(),
                            output=True)
        for frame in out:
            stream.write(frame)
```

Но получал ошибку:

```
    with audio_stream.output('pipe:', format='rawaudio', layout='stereo') as out:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще самому реализовать логику для работы с контекстным менеджером, я накидал небольшой код, он должен сработать для вас:

```
import pyaudio
import ffmpeg
import subprocess


class Player:
    def __init__(self, url:str):
        self.url = url
        self.ffmpeg_command = ffmpeg.compile(
            ffmpeg.output(ffmpeg.input(self.url), 'pipe:', format='wav', acodec='pcm_s16le', ac=2, ar='44100'),
            overwrite_output=True)
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.audio.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=2,
            rate=44100,
            output=True
        )
        self.process = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.ffmpeg_command,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                                        shell=True)
        return self

    def read(self):
        raw_audio = self.process.stdout.read(4096)
        if not raw_audio: raise RuntimeError("Ошибка воспроизведения")
        self.stream.write(raw_audio)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.audio.terminate()
        self.process.kill()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Player(url='https://listen4.myradio24.com/5129') as player:
        while True:
            player.read()
```

Comment: Ничего не играет и висит в бесконечном цикле.

Comment: Что на самом деле странно ибо у меня всё работает без проблем, я обновил немного скрипт и теперь в случае если скрипт не получает данных вылетает с ошибкой. При возможности пройдитесь пожалуйста по скрипту дебагером и сообщите если найдёте ошибку

Comment: "ошибка воспроизведения" да. Попробовал через браузер посмотреть, там вроде бы `mpeg`, а не `wav`. Но если у вас работает, значит что-то у меня с драйверами или python, буду смотреть.

Comment: попробовал на другом компьютере, тоже под Windows, играет без проблем  Теперь уже спортивный интерес разобраться в чём разница между машинами.

Comment: Расскажите потом к чему пришли, мне тоже интересно :)

Comment: две проблемы у меня было. [Первая](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/174#issuecomment-561546739), вторая — установка библиотеки не добавляет **ffmpeg** в PATH, поэтому `choco install ffmpeg`. Понял, что что-то не так, когда увидел exit code 1 у `popen`, такой же и в `os.system(' '.join(ffmpeg_command))`. Можно ещё проверку на установленный **ffmpeg** добавить к вашему коду :)